# How do I display "X" by entering X, in R?

Tags: r, metaprogramming, generic-function

How can one capture the *object name* of an argument to a generic function call?

A toy example will clarify the question and, as I understand it, core issue. Consider an object of some S3 class:

```
X <- structure("blah", class = "SomeClass")
```

For `SomeClass` objects, I want to make a (silly) `print` method that simply prints the *name* of the object. In particular, when I enter `X` at the console, I want to see the name `X`:

```
> X
X
```

I tried to implement this with the following method:

```
print.SomeClass <- function(y) cat(deparse(substitute(y)))
```

Invoking `print(X)` gives `X`, as expected. But just entering `X` (uppercase) at the console gives `x` (lowercase):

```
> print(X)
X
> X
x
```

What gives? I surmise this `x` is derived from the name of the argument of the generic function `print`. How must I modify `print.SomeClass` so that directly invoking `X` gives `X`?

The issue seems to be a discrepancy between displaying an object via bare invocation at the console and displaying an object via `print`—they are not exactly equivalent. I suspect, I may need to supply `substitute()` with a specific environment elsewhere on the call stack. But in that case, I don't know which one would bridge the discrepancy.